# Kerberos authentication ticket - Event ID 4768 - Audit failure

Tags: authentication, active-directory, windows-server-2008, kerberos, spn

I am using kerberos to authenticate a user and its failing. Audit failure details in event viewer are following

```
A Kerberos authentication ticket (TGT) was requested.

Account Information:
    Account Name:        ax
    Supplied Realm Name:    TEST.COM
    User ID:            NULL SID

Service Information:
    Service Name:        krbtgt/TEST.COM
    Service ID:        NULL SID

Network Information:
    Client Address:        ::ffff:2.2.2.60
    Client Port:        38532

Additional Information:
    Ticket Options:        0x40800000
    Result Code:        0x6
    Ticket Encryption Type:    0xffffffff
    Pre-Authentication Type:    -

Certificate Information:
    Certificate Issuer Name:        
    Certificate Serial Number:    
    Certificate Thumbprint:        

Certificate information is only provided if a certificate was used for pre-authentication.

Pre-authentication types, ticket options, encryption types and result codes are defined in RFC 4120.
```

The result code 0x6 means that user doesn't exist in Kerberos database but i have a user already configured in AD.
        This is windows server 2008 (non-R2) and user account name is "axtest" and User logon name is "ax/mytest". The domain name is test.com. From wireshark, i can see that my client is sending AS-REQ which has correct 2 name string items ax & mytest. I am not sure why is it failing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Let's see a screenshot of the user account in AD, showing the Account tab, redacting anything you feel necessary.

Comment: i have added couple of screenshots. i was testing with other user accounts and removed the one that i mentioned earlier in my question. The above account settings are exactly same as my old account and i am getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Since i was running old Microsoft 2008 version, it was missing the hotfix (KB951191). Installing that resolved the issue.

Comment: A missing hotfix KB951191 caused the issue?  Fascinating... Thanks for getting back to this thread.